# HTML5 Drag and Drop duplicating issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

new here (new account. Been here for ages though)
I have a problem where when I try and use the html5 drag and drop. It duplicates the item when I drop the element and keeps the original element at its original location. But if I drag the original again to the copy, it puts the element inside the copy. Why? and How would I fix this? If you need to see the code I'm using, it's literally the default HTML5 drag and drop from w3.

Comment: What code you're using?  A DOM element can exist in only a single place in the document, if the element is being duplicated, it means you're cloning it somewhere.